# How to check that ObservableCollection has duplicate data or not?

Tags: asp.net, wpf

I have a collection `ItemDemandCollection` which is connected to a data grid. If a user enters the same data then an alert message needs to show the duplication of data.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **ICollection.Contains(T)**, for the entered data.
Find more about [Collection.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132407.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What data are you entering in the datagrid? What type is your each item of?

E.g. You might be binding a collection of instances of `Employee` class and showing Employee ID and Name as columns on the datagrid.

If so, duplication can occur on `EmployeeName` property or `EmployeeID` properties. But duplicates on `EmployeeName` can be allowed as any two employees can have same `Name`. But same IDs are not allowed.

So when an ID is entered and you loose focus, the item gets added, and it raises `ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged` event. Handle this event and in the handler, you can check if "e.Action == Add", if so perform a lambda query on existing items and check on the `ID` property for the entered value ....

```
 if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add 
    && MyItems.Where(
         item => item.EmployeeID == e.NewItems[0].EmployeeID).Count() > 1)
 {
     //Duplicates found!
 }
```

If this is not helping you then please elborate on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to do something similar in WinRT and this worked for me, I think it should also for WPF. Similar to WPF-it's answer, more or less. This assumes that each data item you have has some unique ID (or any unique value), and all items (in collection and which you're about to add) have this same unique id field.

```
var duplicates = yourCollectionOfItems.Where((item) => item.UniqueID == itemYouAreAboutToAddToCollection.UniqueID);

if (duplicates.Any()) throw new SomeDuplicateException(); 
// And/or show your alert dialog, in this case.
```

"if (duplicates.Any())" is the same as "if (duplicates.Count() > 0)".

Could also be chained into one line w/o using a "duplicates" variable; e.g.

```
if (yourCollectionOfItems.Any((item) => item.UniqueID == itemYouAreAboutToAddToCollection.UniqueID))
{ 
    // Do error handling here.
}
```